# In a makefile, is there a way to redirect $(warning) or $(info) statements to file

Tags: debugging, makefile, gnu

Note that I do not want to redirect *all* make output to file. I only want the output from a $(warning) command to file.

```
someTarget:
    $(warning building $@ using $?) >> someLogFile.txt
```

My example above does not redirect the output from $(warning to someLogFile.  Is there a way to do it?  Maybe redirect it to a variable and then echo that to a file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to redirect $(warning) or $(info) statements to file?

Here's one for GNU Make, but it's not pretty:

**Makefile**

```
LOG := log.txt
TARGET_ACQUIRED = \
    $(shell echo 'NO_SUCH_TARGET:' | $(MAKE) --eval='$$(info Target acquired: $@...)' -s -f - >> $(LOG))

target_a: target_b
    $(TARGET_ACQUIRED)
    touch $@

target_b:
    $(TARGET_ACQUIRED)
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -f target_* $(LOG)
```

With which you'll get:

```
$ make
touch target_b
touch target_a
$ cat log.txt
Target acquired: target_b...
Target acquired: target_a...
```

To understand this ruse, see the [GNU make commandline options](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html).

If you want this for the purpose of debugging a makefile, you'd probably
fare better with GNU Make's `--debug` options, documented at the same place.